# Visual Studio 2013 has no option for "Go to Definition" for CSS classes

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

According to documentation I could find for VS2012 I should be able to right click a class name in my code and go to definition.  It will then open the correct CSS file and bring me to where it is declared.

I am using VS2013 and it has no option for this.  I am using a website project and just using .html files.

The design I am working on has several CSS files so this would be a really handy feature for me to have.  Has it changed in VS2013?  Anyone know why I cant see this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try WebEssentials. It has build in feature for this: http://vswebessentials.com/features/html#definition

Comment: Upgraded from 2012 to 2013 and didn't realise that I had this installed before and it was giving me this feature.  Thank you for pointing it out to me as it was driving me mad!

Comment: Shift+F12 will help you to find in files, you will see result in Find Result window, I believe you need to install WebEssentials

Answer (score 0):

I believe this a configuration issue with your copy of VS2013. Try going to a class name and hitting F12. If that takes you to the definition, something is wrong with your context menu.

Comment: F12 doesn't work.  Any idea how to fix context menu?